# should I handle the master redis ip by myself in redis single master multi slave cluster

Tags: redis

I am using a single master multi slave redis cluster in kubernetes v1.16.0,but today I found the master ip changed(another node change to master and legacy master change to slave) and cause my cluster down. I am install my redis like this:

```
./helm install stable/redis-ha --generate-name -n middleware
```

and specify ip through the master service ip. what should I do to make it handle it automaticlly.This is service status:

[image]

Comment: Why did your cluster auto switch master and slave? Did you run in sentinel mode?

Comment: runing single master multi slave model @Gawain

Comment: I think redis-ha will start with sentinel by default. If so, master/slave will not be static and can be switched. Please check your deployment to verify if there are sentinel or not. If sentinel exist, you should config your application with sentinel